# Simple dom html for get link and username

Tags: php

I am developing php code to extract username and its link from html code below.

```
enter code here<div class="outter page_search_results">
    <div class="typemembers">
                        <div class="dataitem single" id="div_save_search" style="display: none">
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="entry" id="save_search_response">
                        <form name="form_save_search" id="form_save_search" action="" onsubmit="save_search();return false;" method="post">
                            <div class="fieldset">
                                <dl class="fieldset fieldgrid">
                                    <dt><label for="field_search_save">Diese Suche speichern</label></dt>
                                    <dd><input name="search_save" type="text" class="text" id="field_search_save" style="width: 200px" value="" maxlength="128"></dd>
                                    <dd class="submit report">
                                        <input id="save_search_submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Jetzt Suchen" type="submit">
                                        <div class="progress" id="save_search_progress"></div>
                                        <div class="clear"></div>
                                    </dd>
                                </dl>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="hidden" id="field_hash" name="hash" value="nj1cxyqjj7zr5xn3nkh7x8zszjqsq987">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="dataitem single" id="div_reorder" style="display: none">
            <div class="form">
                <form name="form_reorder" action="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/search/nj1cxyqjj7zr5xn3nkh7x8zszjqsq987/" method="post">
                    <div class="fieldset">
                        <dl class="fieldset fieldgrid">
                            <dt><label for="field_orderby">Reihenfolge</label></dt>
                            <dd><select class="select" name="orderby" id="field_orderby"><option value="lastvisit" selected="selected">Letzter Besuch</option><option value="joindate">Anmeldedatum</option><option value="averagerating">Profilbewertung</option></select></dd>
                            <dt><label for="field_direction">Richtung</label></dt>
                            <dd><select class="select" name="direction" id="field_direction"><option value="desc" selected="selected">Z-A</option><option value="asc">A-Z</option></select></dd>
                            <dt><label for="field_display_type">Anzeigetyp</label></dt>
                            <dd><select class="select" name="display_type" id="field_display_type"><option value="0" selected="selected">Detailiert</option><option value="1">Übersicht</option></select></dd>
                            <dd class="submit"><input class="submit" name="submit" value="Jetzt Suchen" type="submit"></dd>
                        </dl>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
                                                            <div class="dataitem odd  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                        <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/cptcrunch"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/templates/blackdates/media/user_picture_none.gif" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/cptcrunch">cptcrunch</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>SH, Flensburg&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem even  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                        <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/Kingcool"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/templates/blackdates/media/user_picture_none.gif" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/Kingcool">Kingcool</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>NDS, Leer&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem odd  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                                            <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/philipp_lulu"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/media/uploads/6/5/2/1/32524/t_photo_32524yjph3aumojzevk58tz7cayu.jpg" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/philipp_lulu">philipp_lulu</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>MvP, Ludwigslust&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem even  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                        <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/friend1304"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/templates/blackdates/media/user_picture_none.gif" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/friend1304">friend1304</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>SH, Husum&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem odd  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                                            <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/SandroNB"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/media/uploads/2/7/1/3/32219/t_photo_32219phjxqau9vxrkgt7nam5aeb5.jpg" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/SandroNB">SandroNB</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>MvP, Neubrandenburg&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem even  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                                            <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/immerda"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/media/uploads/6/0/0/4/31889/t_photo_31889cvmkuuyr9vv9pgo2m23dc1b.jpg" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/immerda">immerda</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>NDS, Leer&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem odd  search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                        <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/Flo98"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/templates/blackdates/media/user_picture_none.gif" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/Flo98">Flo98</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>HB, Bremen&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                                <div class="dataitem even dataitemlast search_item">
                    <table class="plain">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="image">
                                                            <a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/niklas1365"><img src="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/media/uploads/2/5/4/5/31695/t_photo_0s8sue8kan9h5p8z6vq7gu9hnc76.jpg" alt="" border="0"><br></a>
                                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="data">
                                <div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/niklas1365">niklas1365</a>
</h2>

                                    <dl class="datainfo">
                                                    <dt>Alter:</dt>
    <dd>18&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Geschlecht:</dt>
    <dd>ein Mann&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Suche:</dt>
    <dd>eine Frau&nbsp;</dd>
            <dt>Stadt:</dt>
    <dd>SH, Tornesch&nbsp;</dd>
                                        </dl>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
                                </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

But I would like to extract from this part.

```
enter code here<div class="datainfo">
                                    <h2 class="inner">
<a href="http://verliebt-im-norden.de/philipp_lulu">philipp_lulu</a>
</h2>
```

Then assign $username = philipp_lulu;
$link = http://verliebt-im-norden.de/philipp_lulu;

Could you please help me?

Thank you,
Ponomy

Comment: Hi, your effort so far? =)

Comment: I am new in simple dom html.

Comment: Start by scraping links. Then process the link's html. This will get you started: http://www.lightspeedpos.com/retail/retaileasy/2007/08/scraping-links-with-php/

Comment: @user41065 So what? Get SimpleDOM running first. Check the official documentation on their website. StackOverflow is not a place where you can just request people to do your work for you. Try something, and if you get stuck, ask a specific question.

Comment: @Mave Thank for your guideline